# Android Collapsible & Expand Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

Basically I am trying to do an animation for layout upon user on touch the button. Here is the explanation:

I have a base mapview and on top of that, I am trying to put a linear layout to shows news feed. And normally the linear layout will be **collapsed** with an **expand** button. So when user on touch and drag down the button, the **linear layout will expand**.

I have experienced with this using JQuery and Javascript. However, I have no idea how to do this in Android.

I have found some researches: [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) and I not sure how to implement it. And here is my layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.esri.android.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        initExtent="21801.3, 25801.0, 33218.7, 44830.0">
    </com.esri.android.map.MapView>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navDrawerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dimgrey"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null">
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking me specifically. I only edited your question as you had added some incorrect tags.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, I thought you have some ideas to do it? I still can't figure it out tho

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Any guides???